# not being able to render a category page with products related to that category

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
"use client";

import { useMyContext } from "@/app/utils/context";
import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { SubCategory } from "@/app/utils/context";
import Image from "next/image";
import { fetchSubCategories } from "../utils/api";

type Props = {
  subCategory: { [key: number]: SubCategory };
};

const SubCategoryPage: React.FC<Props> = ({ subCategory }) => {
  const { subcategories, setSubCategories } = useMyContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    getSubcategories();
  }, []);

  const getSubcategories = async () => {
    fetchSubCategories().then((res) => {
      console.log("Subcategories:", res);
      setSubCategories(res.data);
    });
  };

  console.log("Sub-Category:", subcategories);
  if (!subcategories) {
    // Handle the case when subcategories is undefined or null
    return <div>No subcategories available.</div>;
  }
  const subcategoryArray = Object.values(subcategories);

  return (
    <>
      {subcategoryArray.map((subcategory) => (
        <main className="flex items-center justify-center" key={subcategory.id}>
          <div>
            <h1 className="text-4xl">{subcategory.attributes.title}</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Image
              src={subcategory.attributes.image?.data?.url}
              alt={subcategory.attributes.title}
              width={1200}
              height={600}
            />
          </div>
          <div>{subcategory.attributes.description}</div>
          <div>
            <ProductCard products={subcategory.attributes.products.data} />
          </div>
        </main>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default SubCategoryPage;
```

This page is rendering all the subcategories data at the same time. I want it to render one page dynamically based on the sub-category title user clicked in the navbar component. I wnat to render only the data related to that sub-category title which the user click on that page

This is the navbar component

```
const renderSubCategories = (subCategoryData: SubCategory[]) => {
    if (!router) {
      return null; // Return null or handle the situation when the router is not available
    }
    return subCategoryData.map((subCategory: SubCategory) => (
      <Link
        key={subCategory.id}
        href={"/subcategory"}
        as={`/gifts-for-${subCategory.attributes.title
          .toLowerCase()
          .replace(/\s+/g, "-")}`}
        passHref
      >
        <div className="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100">
          {subCategory.attributes.title}
        </div>
      </Link>
    ));
  };
```